# Footer commands don't work properly the second time

Tags: excel, vba, footer

Note: My Excel version is German, in case that changes anything. One problem with this could be that [the VBA codes for headers and footers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/workbooks-and-worksheets/formatting-and-vba-codes-for-headers-and-footers) work differently.

My code (works the first time with an empty footer):

```
Sub updateFootnote_Click()
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Table2.Activate
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftFooter = "Cell Value: " & Table1.Cells(15, 4).Value
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = "Test" & Chr(10) & "Seite &S von &A"
    End With
    Table1.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
End Sub
```

Footer result 1 (upon initial execution with an empty footer):

```
Cell Value: 1  |                   |  Test<\n>Seite 1 von 46
' <\n> = linebreak
```

Footer result 2 (executed method for the second time):

```
Cell Value: 1  |  von &[Register]  |  Test<\n>Seite 1 von 46
' <\n> = linebreak
```

Footer result 3 (executed method for the third time):

```
Cell Value: 1  |  ~von &[Seite]&[Pfad] von~  |  Test<\n>Seite 1 von 46
' <\n> = linebreak
' ~Test~ = *strikethrough formated text*
```

And so on, and so on. It keeps getting worse every time I execute the function again, until you delete the footer manually. (Setting all three footer parts to an empty string using code does not work)

On top of that, *wanted changes* in the code or referenced cell values take no effect after the first successful code execution.

I'd appreciate it if anyone could tell me what is going so horribly wrong here, that the repeated execution of a few setter methods can result in different outcomes and wanted changes get ignored after the footer is not empty anymore.

Comment: What's the purpose of activating `Table1` and `Table2`? Do you actually want to update `Table2`'s footer and not `ActiveSheet` (at the point of executing `updateFootnote_Click` sub)?

Comment: `updateFootnote_Click` is called from `Table1`. Activating the sheets in this order with disabled screen updates, updates the footer of `Table2` from another worksheet - aka `Table1` - without visibly changing the active sheet. But that is just for the looks and has nothing to do with the described problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue so I'm not sure what went wrong (some other factors?) But if you change `With ActiveSheet.PageSetup` to `With Table2.PageSetup` , you can change `Table2`'s footer directly so you won't actually need to disable `ScreenUpdating`, `PrintCommunication` or even `Activate` both worksheet.

Comment: Your `RightFooter` doesn't seems to match with Footer result 1 either, it should return `Test<\n>Seite _von [Sheet Name]_`  with strikethough applied to text within _. Do you get the same problem if you try it on a new workbook?

Comment: yes it does match the footer result 1. In the german version of Excel &S stands for page number and &A for total ammount of pages. Also i found a misspelled valable: it's supposed to be `Table1.Cells(15, 4).Value` not `ControllPanel.Cells(15, 4).Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out, what caused it.

There seems to be a problem with the header / footer codes in VBA (German Excel Version) if the PrintCommunication is disabled. If that is the case &P becomes &S, &N -> &A, &F -> &N and so on. Furthermore the codes get probably converted back and forth when executed multiple times causing even more chaos.

In a nutshell - the following line can cuase a ton of problems:

```
Application.PrintCommunication = False
```

Leaving it out solves the problem.
The working code then comes out to:

```
Sub updateFootnote_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Table2.Activate
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftFooter = "Cell Value: " & Table1.Cells(15, 4).Value
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = "Test" & Chr(10) & "Seite &P von &N"
    End With
    Table1.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a very similar problem.

I have a worksheet with a lot of macros and vba code which I wanted to protect from being altered by others.
Since there is no way to protect headers and footers i found a tip to just set them within my vba code upon opening the worksheet.
This seemed to work fine, but I wanted to extend this method to the BeforePrint and BeforeSave functions as well.
I started wondering that the footer looked different everytime I printed it using a button that calls

Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show

It seems to somehow cycle through different footer variations each time I click the button and cancel the print dialogue (I can already see it when I use the preview within the print dialogue.
So basically, when I "click print -> preview -> cancel" three times in a row, I see 3 different footer variations in the preview, like the v2.5 being in the left footer, next time, left footer contains the file path etc.

I have tried several things to narrow down the problem, but I have absolutely no explanation what is happening and how I can prevent it from happening.
Someone suggested it might be an issue of Screen updating, or about enabling/disabling events.. so I included function calls to test if it makes any difference... BUT IT DOESN'T.
(These tests are the reson for the various commented lines, to enable/disable different variations of the code for testing purposes)

For now, all >I can do is give up, remove the print button and hope no one modifies my header/footer before printing.

Has anyone an idea whats happening and why? And how i can achieve my original goal?

BTW: It's a document I created to be shared with multiple people at work, used on several different workstations. The only common thing is we use the same Office Professional Plus 2016 Suite on the company workstations.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    Call ProtectHF
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Call ProtectHF
End Sub

Private Sub ProtectHF()
'
' Kopf- und Fußzeile schützen, in dem sie z.B. bei jedem Start hier gesetzt werden!
'
'    Application.EnableEvents = False
'
'    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeader = ""
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = ""
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightHeader = ""
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftFooter = "Schaltauftrag"
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter = "v2.5"
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightFooter = "17.07.2023"
'    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'
'    Application.EnableEvents = True

'
'With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
'    .LeftHeader = ""
'    .CenterHeader = ""
'    .RightHeader = ""
'    .LeftFooter = "Schaltauftrag"
'    .CenterFooter = "v2.5"
'    .RightFooter = "17.07.2023"
'End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It seems like the above question already has a solution. If that solution doesn't work for you, it's better for you to create a new question instead of posting an answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).